# Pass column name as parameter to PostgreSQL using psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, parameters, psycopg2

I'm trying to add columns to a table using `psycopg2`

`row1` below is a list of column names to be added to the table. I can do it manually but when I try to do it programatically I get an error.

```
for c in row1:
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE HHV2PUB ADD COLUMN %s text", (c,))
```

The error is:

```
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE HHV2PUB ADD COLUMN %s text", (c,))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'HOUSEID'"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE HHV2PUB ADD COLUMN 'HOUSEID' text
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the single quotes `''`

Comment: that single quotes  in `'HOUSEID'` (%s) should be the problem

Comment: @varchar: Yes, and those single quotes are there because the OP used SQL parameters.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As of Psycopg 2.7 there is the safe [`sql` module](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html):

```
from psycopg2 import sql

query = sql.SQL("alter table t add column {} text")

row1 = ('col1', 'col2')
for c in row1:
    cursor.execute(query.format(sql.Identifier(c)))
```

With 2.6 and earlier:

Use `psycopg2.extensions.AsIs`

> [Adapter conform to the ISQLQuote protocol useful for objects whose string representation is already valid as SQL representation.](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs)

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost4 port=5432 dbname=cpn")
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = "alter table t add column %s text"

row1 = ('col1', 'col2')
for c in row1:
    cursor.execute(query, (AsIs(c),))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Note that this is no safer than using straight-up interpolation of the object name.

Comment: Using `sql.Identifier()` is safe, yes: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/577
But `AsIs()` is not.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot use SQL parameters for *SQL object names*. SQL parameters quote values explicitly so that they cannot be interpreted as such; that is one of the major reasons to use SQL parameters *otherwise*.

You'll have to use string interpolation here. Be *extremely careful* that you are not using user input to produce `c` here:

```
for c in row1:
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE HHV2PUB ADD COLUMN %s text" % c)
```

Psycopg2 does give you a method to mark parameters as 'already escaped' with [`psycopg2.extensions.AsIs()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs), but the intention is for this to be used on already escaped *data* instead.

A much better idea is to use the [`psycopg2.sql` extension](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) to manage correct identifier escaping:

```
from psycopg2 import sql

for c in row1:
    cur.execute(
        sql.SQL("ALTER TABLE HHV2PUB ADD COLUMN {} text").format(
            sql.Identifier(c)))
```