# How to update the table dynamically in psycopg2

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I have following PostgreSQL query

```
cond = {'notified':'100','token':'123','usage':'kart_user'}
sql = "UPDATE {} set notified = %(notified)s where token = %(token)s".format(cond['usage'])
result = self.cur.execute(sql,cond)
result = self.dbconn.commit()
return res
```

Now, the problem I facing in the case of dynamic dictionary. 
dictionary keys and value is not fixed. 
Eg-

```
cond = {'notified':'100','token':'123','custid':'1v123','buyer':'yes','usage':'kart_user'}
```

How i can rewrite above update query in the case of dynamic keys? 
Thank you for your response.

Comment: Just a quick security tip! NEVER pass your query parameters in with `format()`! That opens you up for SQL injection. See [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) on how to do it properly.

Comment: If you want to pass column as parameter, look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289957/pass-column-name-as-parameter-to-postgresql-using-psycopg2