# How to add escape with in python """ quote string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, lambda

i am trying to integrate my AWS lambda function to query my postgresql.

```
sql_update_query = """update  "YP_SUPPLIERS" set %s =%s where "YP_SUPPLIERS"."supplierID"= %s"""
    cursor.execute(sql_update_query, (key[0],value[0],supplierID))
```

Apparently while  creating the table "" where used. This is pretty hectic to work around this.

error

```
syntax error at or near "'supplierName'"
LINE 1: update  "YP_SUPPLIERS" set 'supplierName'='key' where "YP_SU...
```

it seems set %s who's value is supplierName should be with in "".
Can any one let me know a work around or how can i implement this properly please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass column name as parameter to PostgreSQL using psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289957/pass-column-name-as-parameter-to-postgresql-using-psycopg2)

Comment: @MikeOrganek i am afraid it doesn't have already implemented what was mentioned in there . Thank you though :)

Comment: Yes.  It does.  The error you are getting is because `supplierName` is a column name.  When the `execute` substitutes it as a parameter, it treats `supplierName` like a literal value.

Comment: @MikeOrganek so how can i have supplierName taken as a column name.
i am using this because i will be unaware of the column name to be modified. which will be sent from API query parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [SQL composition](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) feature of psycopg2

```
from psycopg2 import sql

sql_update_query = sql.SQL(
    """update "YP_SUPPLIERS" 
          set {} = %s,
              {} = %s
        where "YP_SUPPLIERS"."supplierID" = %s""").format(
                                                    sql.Identifier(key[0]),
                                                    sql.Identifier(key[1])
                                                   )

cursor.execute(sql_update_query, (value[0], value[1], supplierID))
```

Comment: This worked suppose if i have multiple column to update ? 

will i add 

"""update "YP_SUPPLIERS" set {} = %s set{} = %s

        where "YP_SUPPLIERS"."supplierID" = %s""").format(sql.Identifier(key[0],key[1]))

Comment: @sumanthshetty  No.  You will need to call `sql.Identifier()` once for each format substitution.  I will update my answer.  If you pass multiple arguments to `sql.Identifier()`, then it constructs an identifier like `"FirstString"."SecondString"`

Comment: got it . thank you so much for the explanation it helped me to understand it much clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```py
sql_update_query = """update  YP_SUPPLIERS set %s =%s where supplierID= %s"""
cursor.execute(sql_update_query%(key[0],value[0],supplierID))
```